# How to invert django models.BooleanField's value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have some `models.BooleanFields` and I want them to be displayed inverted in Django Admin view.
Is there a way to do it with a function with fieldname parameter?

For example, for `admin.py`:

```
list_display = (inverted('booleanField1'),
                'booleanField2',
                inverted('booleanField3'))
```

Also it is important to remain those icons that are default for `BooleanField`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method on your model admin that inverts the value, and use that in [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['inverted_field1']

    def inverted_field1(self, obj):
        return not obj.field1
    inverted_field.boolean = True
    inverted.short_description = "Not %s" % fieldname
```

Setting the `boolean` attribute to `True` means that the field will have the same on/off icon as the original boolean field, and the `short_description` attribute allows you to change the column's title.

Since `list_display`accepts callables, you should be able to create a function `inverted` that returns a callable for a given fieldname:

```
def inverted(fieldname):
    def callable(obj):
        return not getattr(obj, fieldname)
    callable.boolean = True
    callable.short_description = "Not %s" % fieldname
    return callable

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [inverted('field1')]
```

Comment: Now I'm having an error when trying to add some records: models.py, line 290, in __new__
    message = message % (', '.join(missing_fields),
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, function found

Comment: There's not enough information to tell what the problem is there. Please don't post tracebacks in the comments, they are not very readable. Unless this is directly related to the code above, please ask a new question. I haven't tested the `inverted()` function above, but I don't think it would cause that error.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm new in the community. As for function, It does cause the error, because if I try to add something without using `inverted()` function, it works okay. As far as I understood the function may work if it will be represented as a string. Is it possible?

Comment: Make sure that you are passing a string to the `inverted` function, e.g. `inverted('field1')`.

Comment: Double checked. The string is passed to the function. As I said, it inverts the value as it should, I just cann't add or edit records.

Comment: I have tested the code and do not get that error. The `list_display` isn't used on the add/edit pages so I don't see how it would cause a problem. You haven't showed the code you are using or the full traceback, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Course_detail(request,id):
course = Course.objects.get(id=id)
course.views =+1
course.Situation ^= 1 # Operation not #True and False after click
course.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Using a XOR as a NOT although works in this case is not that readable. From the Zen of Python: "_Readability counts._"